# What plants are these?

Tags: identification, vegetables, fruit-trees, plant-care

I threw a bunch of seeds and fruits over the year to my backyard and now two plants showing up:

[image]

[image]

I am just curious if they are anything valuable before I pull them. I am in Pacific Northwest.

Thanks.

Comment: one identification per question please, can you split this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upper one looks like [pumpkin](https://www.dobies.co.uk/Garden/Vegetables/Vegetable+Plants/All+Vegetable+Plants/Pumpkin+Plants+-+F1+Windsor_MH3783.htm), or some family member. The second one is [avocado](https://inhabitat.com/how-to-grow-an-avocado-tree-from-an-avocado-pit/). Did you eat those recently?

Comment: Oh yes, we had both eaten and threw the seeds there..haha